# Octave issue runnig Matlab file at if x == 0 && strmatch(xx,' ');

Tags: matlab, octave

Ok, I'm trying to figure out why Octave is having an issue running a Matlab code I received.  Nothing appears obviously wrong but maybe there is some difference Octave is getting stuck on.

So the matlab file reads a text file, picks out the desired data, and creates a struct.  It is reading in the file correctly and attampting to output a struct but the struct is empty.  I believe I found where it is getting holed up, but I don't see why it would be stuck there.

```
% If not at the end of the file, search for the desired information.
while (current_line ~= -1) && (epoch_count < max_epochs)


    %Check if this line is a comment line.
    if isempty(strfind(current_line,'COMMENT') )


    % Check event flag
    event_flag = str2num(current_line(27:29));
    event_flag_more_strict = current_line(27);

    if event_flag == 0 && strmatch(event_flag_more_strict,' ')

    yr = adjustyear(str2num(current_line(2:3)));

    % Get the time for this data epoch.
    current_time = [ yr ; str2num(current_line(5:6)) ; ...
            str2num(current_line(8:9)) ; str2num(current_line(11:12)) ; ...
            str2num(current_line(14:15)) ; str2num(current_line(16:26)) ]';
.
.
.
```

The problem I'm having is currently in this area of the code.  Current_line is a vector of values found in each line.  If that line isn't a comment and a specific value in the line matches the event_flags then do some work on extracting the values you want.  I've checked the isempty section and made sure the flags were working correctly.  But for some reason it doesn't enter the second if statement.  Is there something Octave won't accept about that statement?

I have Octave 4.0.3.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, yes, octave seems to behave differently from matlab in the case of `' '`:

In octave (4.0.3):

```
>> strmatch(' ', ' ') % octave
ans = [](0x1)
```

In matlab (2013b):

```
>> strmatch(' ', ' ') % matlab
ans =
     1
```

This may or may not be a bug in octave, but either way it seems this function is being deprecated in favour of `strncmp` anyway (both in octave and matlab).

Comment: In the documentation both MATLAB and Octave claim, "Any trailing space characters in str or strarray are ignored when matching." (or equivalent statement). The behaviour for matching empty strings is unclear, Octave gives an empty (or null) result in this case.

Comment: matlab also mentions plan for deprecation, but it's still there in 2016b.  Also, 2016b advises using startsWith or validatestring.  startsWith appears to be a new 2016b function, a compatible implementation obviously not yet implemented in Octave.  in any case, since it's not known how long the function might stick around an empty set compatibility patch may be warranted.  I'll create an entry at bugs.octave.org

Comment: Thanks all!  This has been pretty informative.  I'm sorry I didn't get back to accept an answer quickly.  I had to get that problem finished.  I'll have to keep a lookout for those changes. 

If I replace the strmatch that deal with empty space with the strncmp would that hopefully fix the issues I was having with Octave and the file?  I just wanted to make sure I understood correctly.  

Oh and for EBH below, I added the double & to the Matlab code so Octave would stop giving me a million error warnings.   I found a mention that that was another difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Octave, but something wrong here even in MATLAB.

`strmatch` returns a number, while when using [`&&` you should use only logicals](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html).

You can either change it to `&` or convert it to logical:

```
logical(strmatch(event_flag_more_strict,' '))
```

or preferably use [`strncmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strncmp.html) or [`strcmp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcmp.html).